# Pass variables form current shell environment to the node app

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

Please help me somebody with passing variables to node app.
Given:
node app on ubuntu
package.json contains

```
scripts {
    start: node index.js
}
```

The app is started with command
npm run start

Problem:
the app requires a ton of environment variables
the app runs on the server so i am not using .env file
variables are exported in the shell so i can verify they are available in the shell before i do npm run start like so
echo $MY_VAR
works

Currently in the sell that has all variables exported when i start the app i get from process.env.MY_VAR is undefined

PS i’d always been using .env file before but now that i want it to run on the server i have no idea what magic is needed to pass variables form current shell environment to the node app.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out. I simply forgot to export the variables that were declared in the current shell.